# Handle two browsers concurrently with WebDriver or WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am planning to test a simple realtime web app. This app is written in JavaScript and it shows the "presence status" of the logged in user. If the userA logs his status is being modified from "Inactive" to "Active". This action is reflected to all other users that are logged in to the application. UserB that is logged in shows realtime the presence of userA to change.

I would like to test this scenario. A test handler opens one browsers, does a write action and at the same time a second browser gets updated.

What tools are available? Can this be done with WebDriver/WebDriverJs? Can I have two threads/sessions handled via WebDriver? Any examples?

Comment: Are you not able to utilise two webdriver instances? I know that would be the simplest way to resolve this situation but obviously its not always the most suitable.

Comment: @MarkRowlands Basically I am asking if it is doable somehow. No code written yet.

Comment: Personally, any time I've needed to perform a test like this, I took the easy way and just instantiated a second browser instance. So for example, `firstDriver.findElement(By.id("doAction")).click(); assertTrue(secondDriver.findElement(By.id("resultOfAction")).isVisible());`

Comment: any examples? tutorials? books? code?

Comment: Are you going to be using a test framework?  Or is that still up for debate?

Comment: I was planning to experiment with WebDriverJs

Comment: I've never used webbdriverJS myself, but a quick read of the documentation does suggest that you wouldn't need to use two separate browser instances - the use of Flows look like they could be the solution to your problem. I'm not very clued into Javascript so I'll have to bow out at this stage, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with WebDriver but if you want to run both browsers in the same machine the best way is to use different browsers so you could have two different sessions.

So try using ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver and you will have two different sessions to test your app.

Comment: The application runs in Chrome only. Is it possible to use two or more instances/sessions of the same driver? Is there any code to share in order to start experimenting?

Answer (score 3):

You can use WebdriverJS to do that. Just create two Webdriver instances and navigate them, for example:

```
var WebdriverJS = require('webdriverjs'),
    assert      = require('assert'),

browser1 = new WebdriverJS({
    desiredCapabilities: {browserName:'chrome'}
}).init().url('http://github.com'),

browser2 = new WebdriverJS({
    desiredCapabilities: {browserName:'chrome'}
}).init().url('http://github.com');

browser1
    .setValue('#js-command-bar-field',['webdriverjs','Enter'])
    .getText('.sort-bar h3',function(err,text) {
        assert(text.indexOf('found 24 repository results') >= 0);
    })
    .end();


browser2
    .setValue('#js-command-bar-field',['linux','Enter'])
    .getText('.sort-bar h3',function(err,text) {
        assert(text.indexOf('We\'ve found 22,466 repository results') >= 0);
    })
    .end();
```

Two Chrome windows get opened and will execute your instructions independently.

Comment: Will this create 2 Chrome instances with isolated cookie starages?

Comment: How can I switch between browsers to be able to see what is going on in one or the other?

Comment: @Dziamid this is an old post of mine. WebdriverJS is obsolete by now and is now called WebdriverIO (http://webdriver.io). It will get a multibrowser feature next week and you will be able to handle multiple browser at the same time. Testing Applications like chats or WebRTC apps will be pretty easy then.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've been using webdriver.io in my last project and have been missing the ability to switch between browsers.

Answer (score 2):

With the later versions of WebDriver.js, all asynchronous operations are managed in control flows. Because the control flow will serialize all operations in the correct order, simply creating multiple driver instances may not be enough. All of the operations on one driver will occur before the operations on the other.

For true parallelization, create multiple control flows. Here is an excerpt from the documentation https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Defining_Multiple_Flows:

```
var terms = [
   'javascript',
   'selenium',
   'webdriver'
];

var flows = terms.map(function(term) {
 return webdriver.promise.createFlow(function() {
   var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();

   driver.get('http://www.google.com');
   driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys(term);
   driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
   driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
     if (title !== (term + ' - Google Search')) {
       throw Error('Unexpected title: ' + title);
     }
   });
 });
});

webdriver.promise.fullyResolved(flows).then(function() {
 console.log('All tests passed!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  Of course one must ensure an updated NodeJs version.  Also, if one fails, they all fail which isn't a great.  Problem is that node will through an exception that one cannot "catch" and handle.  It will kill your script so that others will not complete even if they began successfully.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium Grid option](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) should do the trick. You will find a tutorial [here](http://automatictester.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/selenium-grid-tutorial-from-webdriver-to-grid-2-0/)
which you can adapt using webdriverJS.